# Runtime error in python program converting infix to postfix

Tags: python, runtime-error, postfix-mta

I have written python program that convert infix mathematical expression into postfix. it work for some input very well such as A-((B+C)*D-E)*F or(A+B)*C. but when I submit the code scoring site said that runtime error is exist. can you tell me why my code have runtime-error and how to fix it?

```
str = input()
result = ''
stack = []

def getorder(c):
    return {'*':5, '/':5, '+':3, '-':3, '(':1}[c]

def whoisfirst(x, y):
    if(getorder(x) > getorder(y)):
        return 1;
    elif(getorder(x) < getorder(y)):
        return -1;
    else:
        return 0;

for i in str:
    if(i.isalpha()):
        result += i
    else:
        if (i == '('):
            stack.append(i)
            continue
        elif (i == ')'):
            while True:
                result += stack.pop(-1)

                if(stack[-1] == '('):
                    stack.pop(-1)
                    break
            continue


        if not stack:
            stack.append(i)
        else:
            while (whoisfirst(i, stack[-1]) != 1):
                result += stack.pop(-1)

                if not stack:
                    break
            stack.append(i)

while stack:
    result += stack.pop(-1)

print(result)
```

Comment: is it codechef? did you run or submit?

Comment: It's not codechef it is baekjoon which is korea site. I've run program for some test case and submit it but site said runtime error...